# Storing data in REDUX store using axios React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, mern

I am new to redux and working on a MERN app. I need to use data from a collection "Assetmaster" in a few of the react components.

One option is fetching the data through axios, useEffect and render my table in the react component. But as I need to use this data in other components also i have to dispatch it to the Redux store using useDispatch(). In this case other components can use the data using useSelector().

However I need to know if it is possible to get the data directly in Redux Store centrally without fetching it in any of the components. And in such case do we need to use useEffect to ensure the data is fetched each time any changes in the collection is made to the database through any of the react component.

Comment: This is not answer and neither a solution. But guide you to correct approach. You can choose a loose accomplished flow, you dispatch your request desired action to an async specialist which use a library script designed for you having role only send request to API and get results back to async specialist which tells to redux state of this operation. This is not absolute approach to this but is the widely used. Just check out about redux-saga it perfect fits to your needs

Answer (score 0):

If your useEffect didn't have any dependencies, that's not correct to fetch data because it (useEffect) fetch data only once. also check your dependencies render many time it cause get lag and heavy processing load.

at all, Redeux and redux-toolkit like redux-thunk uses for mange and storing data between components (if you know about design patterns, it like proxy design pattern). if you had sidebar panel or something else that do not need to render client data and save it i recommend you to use contextApi but if you need manage user data or store it some where like server, cookies, local storage,... if recommend to use Redux and redex-toolkit.

To learn about redux and how can work with this tool, i put my sample source code here for you.

[Source code](https://github.com/Up-Menu/MenuTwo/tree/main/src/store)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data in useEffect once when app loads and store it on store. After that you can access data from store without re-fetching.

When a component updates some data on database instead of fetching again just update it on store .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).